# Fastest known algorithm to enumerate k-cliques in a graph for fixed k

Tags: time-complexity, clique, space-complexity

Is the best known algorithm for finding all $k$-cliques in a graph with $n$ nodes, for a fixed $k$, given by https://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/combclique-ipl-g.pdf ? 
The time-complexity of the proposed algorithm is $O(n^k / (\epsilon \log n)^{k-1})$ with $O(n^\epsilon)$ space, for all $\epsilon > 0$. Please let me know if there are more efficient algorithms to enumerate all $k$-cliques in a graph.

Comment: Probably useless comment - have you looked through the papers that cite that article? Available here: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11230550825184440674&as_sdt=5,50&sciodt=0,50&hl=en

Comment: What are your assumptions about the density of the graph? Because it's easy to enumerate $k$-cliques in time $O(m^{k/2})$ and this can be significantly faster for sparse graphs.

Comment: @DavidEppstein I don't make any assumptions about the density of the graph but its interesting to see that better results can be achieved on doing so. I came across some interesting work -> https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3188745.3188810 where they can get the count of $k$-cliques in sublinear time, but they don't enumerate the cliques.

Comment: If you insist on enumerating $k$-cliques, without any assumption on the graph, it seems that you cannot do significantly better than $O({n\choose k})$ because any set of $k$ vertices in a complete graph is a $k$-clique. (I assume you don't allow cheating on the output part.)

Comment: About listing k-cliques for fixed k in sparse graphs: https://papers-gamma.link/paper/32